# Using gwt to change java files

Tags: java, gwt

I am really new to gwt but I have already posted a question and I don't really understand.

I am working on a project that had already been developed. This project uses get and the javascript comes from java files. I wanted to make some changes on one of these java files. SO I was told I needed to download get. This is what I did.

But my php and html files are processed with MAMP.

So now, how do I change the java files ? Where do I put my php and html files to run it on my local server MAMP ? Am I supposed to take the only java files, opening a "WebApp" (as indicated in the get doc), runn it (with an ant build command ?), retrieving some files and put those in my MAMP workspace ?

(I have read the gwt, but I didn't really understand it. I apologize by advance if my question seems too simple)

Thanks, 
Mehdi

Answer (score 0):

The process you described is basically correct. You should have a directory that contains your GWT project. It sounds like you're using `git` as the version control system but if you already have the project checked out then don't worry about it. Now, open your project with Eclipse (you should first install the GWT plugin in Eclipse so that it sets up all the dependencies for you). Once you've made your changes you can build your GWT project either using Eclipse or with ant as you mentioned. The compiled files will usually be placed in a war folder (along with the index.html or whatever entry point html file you are using). Copy these compiled files to your PHP project and deploy.

Comment: Sure. Also, you don't have to copy the war/WEB-INF folder, but copy everything else under war/

Comment: To begin with, I took a java file from my website, RichTextToolbar.java and I made some changes (because first I only need to make some changes to display a nicer toolbar). But I didn t find where to put it in my gwt folder to be ran. Could ypu help?

Comment: Is RichTextToolbar.java a class in your GWT application? If so then when you compile your GWT application it will be part of the generated javascript in your war/ folder. You just need to copy the contents of that folder to your PHP app, nothing else.